# Spring Security cannot retreieve Currently authenticated user

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which uses Spring-Security. In that I need to get the currently authenticated user's object so I can use setUser() method. However the method returns null, the program seems to crash with a null pointer exception. Kindly have a look at the code. I already debugged+try-catch it and it doesn't return the user.

The call getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() throws exception. When I check, it says authentication is null.

I have implemented Spring-Security by implementing the interface UserDetails and UserDetailsService.

Person Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;


    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

 @Transient
    private final String PERMISSION_PREFIX = "ROLE_USER";
    @Transient
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    @Transient
    private String role;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "person1")
  private Set<Notes> notes1;

    public Set<Notes> getNotes1() {
        return notes1;
    }

    public void setNotes1(Set<Notes> notes1) {
        this.notes1 = notes1;
    }
}
```

LoginServiceImpl :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username);

        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }
}
```

Assembler class :

@Service("assembler")

```
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        // Long id = userEntity.getId();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.isActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        User user = new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        return  user;
        }
}
```

// I get error in below method at getPrincipal
PersonServiceImpl :

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private PersonDAO personDAO;
 @Override
    public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() throws Exception{
        Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Person currentUser = (Person) a.getPrincipal();
        if(currentUser == null){
            throw new Exception("No authenticated user retrieved");
        }else {
            System.out.println("We have currently authenticated user");
            return currentUser;
        }
    }
```

Spring Security-xml

```
    <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <!-- Global Security settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http pattern="/" security="none" />

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
         <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>

    </security:port-mappings>
           <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" invalid-session-url="/invalidSession.html">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="3" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/sessionExpired.html"/>
        </security:session-management>
           <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/note/add" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl" />

    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
    </beans:bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: Please give relevant information : *it crashes* : exception + stacktrace, *the method returns null* **what** method, *it doesn't return the user* : **what** call does not return information ...

Comment: @Orici by asking this question you show that you have not done your homework and have not done any research effort. My humble and kind advise would be please start from basics, something that works and learn first how it works otherwise you will hurt yourself and start saying that spring and java sucks and only rails or node can save you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Security retreive user works only with SecurityContextHolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544575/spring-security-retreive-user-works-only-with-securitycontextholder)

Comment: @SergeBallesta : I have edited my post to include the function getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() which crashes. I had my own try-catch block, and the exception reads Authentication is null.

Comment: @Orici that is very clear your authentication does not work as supposed to and you have to make sure you get and instance of Authentication when calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

Comment: Well, I still have no answer, I already have userDetails and UserDetailsService implemented. I wanted basic authentication to just simply work, doesnt seem like the case now. If there are any ideas better then downvoting me, or screwing me for something else, I welcome those. Please keep in mind, I am no expert in Spring Security, If i really knew after all the different ways how Spring Security is used and confusing docs, I would have not even asked the question.

Comment: @Orici I'm trying to help you, but I downvoted because you do not give us relevant information : when there is an exception, please show stacktrace and say at what line it occurs. Add that and I'll remove my downvote ... (and I'll also update my post below ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not still a real answer, but too long to fit in a comment.

You never test if objects returned from other methods are not null before using them. I think that the most probable error is that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` returns `null` causing the NPE on next line. If that's true, that mean that your problem is in the configuration of Spring security. But it is not possible to say more without seeing the bean `userDetailsService`. You say you *implemented userDetail and UserDetailsService* but do not show how.

I advice your to remove remember_me as long as you do not have a working basic configuration, that is one where :

- you have to login before accessing protected pages
- you can find the logged user in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

You will add more functionnalities once this works. If not, it will be very hard to find the causes of your problems.

Edit:

You say the error occurs on line  `Person currentUser = (Person) a.getPrincipal();`. It is now clear that in previous line

```
Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

`getAuthentication()` returned null. It means that for Spring security, there is no currently authenticated user.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I will update the code on monday as I am already home. The implementation of UserDetails and userdetailsServices is fairly common, it is the same, so I didnt upload. Just a comment also would have been enough. I also found one tutorial mentioning how Userdetails and its service should be implemented in service.. I had implemented userdetails in model, and service in service. I will post all spring securiy code that I have done on monday. Will tag you then. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: As discussed on Friday evening, I have added how I have implemented Spring Security. I even referred to http://krams915.blogspot.de/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_3065.html  to verify I am correct.

Comment: I am still on the same problem by the way. Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: So I finally figured out,personService was notinitilized/null as I was using it in another controller. I have casting error now, hopefully last problem from Spring Security so I can get back to Spring.

Comment: I checked if (a==null), it is not. I searched the same question, and many people seemed to have the same problem in different format or manner.

Comment: @Orici. You have too much things for you first Spring security webapp. Use a basic tutorial, or better the first examples from Spring Security reference manual. You will get a minimal but working security config. And then you will add functionalities (and call here for help if stuck somewhere). Begin with just form login, in memory user details service and one protected page, then add your own Dao, then session management, ... Trust me, it is much easier to start that way.